# SQL View, replace a NULL Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL I have a DateField thats showing the current month data. Some of the Dates are NULL and I would like to replace the NULL Date with somethng like the fn NOW() date somehow. Can someone help guide me with updating NULLS in my query? Im using MS SQL 2008 R2.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[001_SubItem_Price].SubItem, { fn NOW() } AS Date, dbo.POTable.Date AS Datefield
FROM         dbo.[001_SubItem_Price] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.POTable ON dbo.[001_SubItem_Price].SubItem = dbo.POTable.Item
WHERE     (MONTH(dbo.POTable.Date) = MONTH(GETDATE())) OR
                      (MONTH(dbo.POTable.Date) IS NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.[001_SubItem_Price].SubItem, dbo.POTable.Date
ORDER BY dbo.[001_SubItem_Price].SubItem
```

[image]

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using? SQL Server, mySql, Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

`...COALESCE(Datefield, GETDATE()) as Datefield`

Answer (score 3):

in SQL server, you would use `isNULL(Column, GetDate())`

or if you have multiple columns, use `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(column1, column2, GETDATE()) as columnName
```

This will return the first non-null item in the list of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ISNULL or COALESCE depending in which context you need it.

There are a few important differences between the two, that you can check out here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Instead of

```
SELECT dateField...
```

use

```
SELECT ISNULL(dateField, GETDATE())...
```

Comment: changed it with GETDATE() but i was just showing ISNULL function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select IsNull(yourdate, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try either

```
ISNULL(dbo.POTable.Date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Datefield
```

or

```
ISNULL(dbo.POTable.Date, GETDATE()) AS Datefield
```

Answer (score -3):

Just make an sql UPDATE SET where Datefield IS NULL and set the value to getdate()

Comment: It's a view so we don't want to `UPDATE`

Comment: Also, I didn't downvote you but I do appreciate the "revenge" downvote.